# supervising child process of restarted process

Tags: erlang, behavior, spawn, erlang-supervisor

I have a structure like this

```
-------------
|Supervisor |
-------------
      |
-------------
|  Child1   |
-------------
      |
-------------
|  Child2   |
-------------
```

In this structure, child1 is supervised and it spawns child2. What I need is to be able to restart child1 when child2 crashes/exits. Which would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: If you allow `Child1` to crash when `Child2` crashes, your supervisor will simply restart it. Is there a compelling reason why your supervisor isn't starting both processes itself?

Comment: Don't trap exit signals from Child2. Child1 should be regular process not the system process. By this when Child2 terminates, Child1 also terminates and supervisor restarts Child1 which inturn starts Child2.

Comment: @sarnold yes, there is. Child1 starts Child2 after it finishes starting a service

Comment: thanks for your answers, I just start Child2 with spawn_link and let them both crash if child2 crashes.

Comment: @sarnold if you reformulate your comment as an answer I could accept it and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow `Child1` to crash when `Child2` crashes, your existing supervisor
will simply restart `Child1`, thus also restarting `Child2`.

But that depends upon `Child1` crashing when `Child2` crashes. Another option
is to insert another supervisor in the process tree:

```
Change this:                          Into this:

+------------+                      +------------+
| Supervisor |                      | Supervisor |
+------------+                      +------------+
      |                                   |
+------------+                      +------------+
|   Child1   |  New supervisor ---> | Supervisor |
+------------+                      +------------+
      |                               |      |
+------------+              +------------+ +---------+
|   Child2   |              |   Child1   | |  Child2 |
+------------+              +------------+ +---------+
      |                                        |
 other service                            other service
```

The new supervisor handles just the two children as their own service, allowing
the death of either one to influence the other in configurable ways.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Erlang documentation: http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html

All you have to do is to rearrange you process-tree and use `one_for_all` restart strategy. In my oppinion Child1 and Child2 should be children of Supervisor.

Or, in case you want to keep things like they are at the moment you have to catch EXIT of process Child2 in process Child1. When EXIT comes to Child1 all Child1 has to return is:

```
{stop, normal, State}
```

and it will be automaticall restarted by Supervisor. Supervisor must be in `permanent` restart mode.